# Como hacer que se detenga el flujo de un for por unos segundos?

Tags: java, java-swing, eclipse, hilos, java-awt

Estoy haciendo un ciclo para mover una imagen de boton en boton desde una posicion inicial a una final de uno en uno a través de un for,  para que se distinga claramente el movimiento establecí un hilo para que espere unos segundos antes de que avance al siguiente boton y ponga la imagen... el caso es que termina el ciclo y los hilos aun no terminan, lo que estoy tratandi de hacer es que el flujo del for se detenga con el hilo y una vez pasado el tiempo siga... este es mi codigo

```
// for que cambia las imagenes de los botones
    for (int i = aux; i < ubicacion; i++) {
                //ubicacion += 1;
                posfr = tablero[i].getReg();
                posfc = tablero[i].getCol();
                vEtiq[posfr][posfc].setIcon(fig);
                Thread t = new Thread(new Hilo()); 
                t.start();
                vEtiq[posfr][posfc].setIcon(null);
            }


//clase del hilo
class Hilo implements Runnable{
    public void run()  {          
         try {
             //Ponemos a "Dormir" el programa durante los ms que queremos
            Thread.sleep(5000);
             
          } catch (Exception e) {
          }
    }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tienes es que como el `Thread.sleep()` lo ejecutas dentro de un hilo distinto al que ejecuta el `for` no ves el efecuto, puesto que no se duerme el hilo que quieres.

Tienes que tener presente que el método `Thread.sleep()` se le aplica al hilo actual y NO al programa como tal.

La solución es que metas el código del método `run()` *runnable* `Hilo` dentro del `for`.

```
for (int i = aux; i < ubicacion; i++) {
    //ubicacion += 1;
    posfr = tablero[i].getReg();
    posfc = tablero[i].getCol();
    vEtiq[posfr][posfc].setIcon(fig);
    
    // Dormir el hilo de ejecución actual
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
    
    vEtiq[posfr][posfc].setIcon(null);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!